# Infinitesimal: does $f(x + dx)$ being defined imples $f(x + dx) - f(x)$ to be infinitesimal too?

Tags: calculus, definition, infinitesimals

I am refreshing my calculus knowledge. One of the textbooks I use states what you can see down below (see the screenshot attached).

The question I have: must not the definition *explicitly* require $f$ to be continuous? Seems I am allowed to define $f$ as following:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 &, x = 0 \\
1 &, x \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

...so $f(0 + dx) = 1$ since $dx > 0$ by definition and thus $0 + dx \neq 0$, which, in turn, implies that $f(0 + dx) - f(0) = 1 - 0 = 1 \neq dy$.

Am I missing something important/obvious here?

[image: The definition.]

Comment: At this level, infinitesimals aren't formally defined, they're just intuitive. They just mean something like "very small compared to some reference scale". so you shouldn't expect to write formal proofs or disproofs. However, formal definitions can be given, and then, yes, you would need $f$ to be continuous (and more) to prove any such claim like "if the input change is small, the output change will be too"

Comment: What textbook? This seems pretty unwieldy. One normally defines the derivative by $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ provided that this limit exists. In particular, it follows that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if this limit exists.

Comment: @JWP_HTX, Michael Corral, "Elementary Calculus". Yet you're right, limits are of course _the_ standard way to define derivative by now; however, historically, that was different. Leibniz proceeded with the infinitisimal approach, so the textbook does present calculus in the both ways. Moreover, infinitisimals are definex axiomatically, rigorously (well, not quite, with acceptable rigorous considering _elementary_ textbook).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this method is much closer to Newton's historical development of calculus (just with borrowing the $dy$ and $dx$ notation from Leibniz).  Principally, you're still talking in the context of _functions_, which seems out of place with Leibniz's more algebraic development.  (it's safer to attribute your method to Bell, as Corral does in your book)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $f(0+dx) - f(0) = 1$, but to take derivative, function **has to** be continuous (at the neighbourhood of the point, you are doing derivative at). If you do limit definition of derivative, you'll get limit of $\frac{1}{x}$, as $x$ approaches $0$, giving $\frac{1}{0}$, which is undefined.

Comment: That's what I thought. Yet had some feeling I might be missing something quite big here. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes $f(dx)-f(0)=1$ in here. The case when we tell the function to he differentiable is when  $\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}$ for every infenitesimal is close to some real number. In our case $\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{dx}$, $\frac{1}{dx}$ will be either infinite negative or infinite positive number, so the function won't be differentiable in 0